# How to efficiently store and multiply arbitrarily large integers mod n

Tags: c, integer

I want to implement a datastructure `struct bignum` to store arbitrarily large integers.

It should also be possible to efficiently multiply the integer modulo n.

I am not looking for any libraries. I just need the conceptual idea of the best way to implement this myself.

I have already seen some implementations of what I am looking for (e.g. storing each decimal digit in a char array). But there has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: `multiply the integer modulo n` Is this a single operation, or two separate operations? `I have already seen some implementations` Please share them. `there has to be a more efficient way.` in 2 mins I've found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69581271/fast-algorithm-for-modular-multiplicatiion which got me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication

Comment: The usual way of implementing bignums is to use arrays of *integers*, not digits.  So you end up doing your arithmetic in base 10000, or base 65536, or base 1000000000, or base 2147483648, or base 4294967296.  Or maybe even base 10000000000000000000 or base 18446744073709551616.

Comment: If you want to calculate a^x mod n, where a, x, and n, fit in standard integer types, you don't need a bignum library.

Comment: What is the modulo `n`? You may not even *need* a big integer. If the modulus and operands never exceed 32-bit you can use 64-bit sum or product and just take the modulus at every step.

Comment: You can look at the gnu multiprecision library: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: As an example of what I meant by "base 2147483648", the 93-bit number 9876543210987654321098765432 can be represented (and pretty easily manipulated) 31 bits at a time by the three numbers 2141633921, 429399921, and 1667282040 (or 0x7fa6bd81, 0x19981f71, 0x6360b478).  (Or you could do it in decimal, base 1000000000, nine digits at a time: 9, 876543210, 987654321, 098765432.)